# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "\',\'\',\'\',\'" at line 1, column 33

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, derby

I am receiving an error when I tried to add quotation. I am trying to get a record from fields and then insert into derby database using Query. 
   I'm getting an error that saying :java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "\',\'\',\'\',\'" at line 1, column 33.

```
String Query = "select * from QUOTATION order by DATE DESC";
                    try {
                        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MavenUp","adminmu","admin");
                            Statement st= conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); 
                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(Query);

                            int id =0;
                rs.beforeFirst();
                if(rs.next())
                            {

                id = rs.getInt(1);

                            id++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                id=1;
                            }
                          String idd = Integer.toString(id);
                          String Query1;
                 Query1 = "Insert into QUOTATION " + "values  ("+idd+"','"+ClientName.getText()+"','"+QuotationNo.getText()+"','"+Date.getDate()+"'}";
                          if(st.executeUpdate(Query1)== 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Your Quote info has been Inserted");
                }
                else
                {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,  "Something went wrong Try again");
                }
                    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (SQLException e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Comment: what query you are executing is wrong coz you are missing single quotes

Comment: 1. Debugger tools are _way_ more useful in those types of question than we are. 2. Please refrain from using string concatenation to build queries - JDBC has a notion of bound parameters, that are extremely useful for queries.

Comment: Then what should i should else string concatenation

Comment: where is missing sinhle quotes?

Comment: Don't try to play games with quotation marks. Use PreparedStatement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
Query1 = "Insert into QUOTATION " + "values  ('"+idd+"','"+ClientName.getText()+"','"+QuotationNo.getText()+"','"+Date.getDate()+"')";
```

Comment: now it give this error
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "}" at line 1, column 78.

Comment: Yeah It work but now its giving this
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 77.

Comment: i think we miss )

Comment: now this 
Caused by: ERROR 42821: Columns of type 'INTEGER' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR'

Comment: insert query syntax is `INSER INTO tablename values(val11, val2);`

Comment: Why you are done this `     String idd = Integer.toString(id);` You are trying to insert `String` data instead of `integer`. So instead `idd` use `id`.

Comment: debug the program you will you will find answer.

Comment: ': ERROR 42821: Columns of type 'INTEGER' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR' 
Still Same @hitesh

Comment: Its an swing base app

Comment: The error itself explaining the error. Cross check your columns data types of table with what values your are trying to insert into it.